# How to pass two or more parameters in Django URL

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I able to pass two or more parameters in Django URL in this way
`api/Data/GetAuditChecklistDataForEdit/HRR6627687%7C458%7CRegular`

It is a get method so I can't get the values of the two parameter (SID, Type) so I'm trying to pass it through the URL

Is it possible to pass two or more parameter in this way

views.py:

```
 @api_view(['GET'])
   def GetAuditChecklistDataForEdit(request, ticket, SID, Type):
    if request.method =='GET':
   
       
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetAuditChecklistDataForEdit] @ticket=%s, @setid=%s, @Type=%s',
        (ticket, SID, Type))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        data =[]
        for row in result_set:
            print("GetAuditChecklistDataForEdit",row[0])
            data.append({
            'QId':row[0],
            'Question':row[1],
            'AnsOption':row[2],
            'Choice':row[3],
            'Agents':row[4],
            'StreamId':row[5],
            'Supervisor':row[6],
            'Action':row[7],
            'subfunction':row[8],
            'region':row[9],
            'Comments':row[10],
            'TicketType':row[11],

            })
        return Response(data)
```

urls.py:

```
path('Data/GetAuditChecklistDataForEdit/<str:ticket>', GetAuditChecklistDataForEdit, name='GetAuditChecklistDataForEdit'),
```

Comment: if you want to pass a fixed number of parameters, then simply include them in url path: `Data/GetAuditChecklistDataForEdit/<str:ticket>/<str:SID>/<str:Type>/`, otherwise send them using url query parameters: `Data/GetAuditChecklistDataForEdit/?foo=&bar=&baz=`

Comment: I don't think information such as ticket IDs should be passed as URL parameters; as URL parameters are never secure and should never contain important information.
Such a method should be of type POST not GET.

Comment: get method  should only  return data  if you want  to create, update or delete then use post method